# Is it possible to set custom colors per status for Friends list in Steam?

Tags: steam

I know there's no built-in way to do this, but I do know that Steam is skinnable, and I have dug around in some of the UI files before and know that they can be edited.  **This question is aimed toward someone with a somewhat in-depth knowledge of Steam's UI files.**

Is there a way to edit the UI files so that people on my Steam Friend's list have different colors depending on their status?  Currently Online/Away/Busy/Snooze all have the same blue color and I would like to differentiate between these in a more obvious way.

Comment: I don't see anything promising in `Steam\resource\styles\steam.styles`, just `Friends.InGameColor`, `Friends.OnlineColor` and `Friends.OfflineColor`. I think if that was possible, some skin would already have it. But hey, I'm not an expert.

Comment: I think you're right, @PiotrKowalski. I've made a few Steam skins before, and those types of properties are read automatically by Steam. I've tried adding my own to the file in the hopes that maybe the properties exist (like `Friends.AwayColor`), but to no avail.

Comment: I figured that might be the case.  That's unfortunate.  I appreciate you guys taking the time to respond.  Who knows... maybe Steam will implement a way to change this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this doesn't give you direct access to the UI files, I found this [tool](http://steamcustomizer.com) that has an option to edit the colors you were talking about.

By downloading a created skin, you could probably hack around in the skin files to find out what's setting the status colors on your friends list.

However, based on the way the fields are labeled, it looks like the three status colors represent Online, Offline, and In-Game. If this is how they are stored in the UI files, I'd guess that you wouldn't be able to set a specific color for Away versus Snooze, for instance.